# Ruby on Rails: uninitialized constant MysqlCompat::MysqlRes

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I tried all the options specified in the link: [uninitialized constant MysqlCompat::MysqlRes (using mms2r gem)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332207/uninitialized-constant-mysqlcompatmysqlres-using-mms2r-gem) but nothing is working.

I have an iMac with Snow Leopard installed. I am currently using the mysql gem version 2.7 and I checked that ruby was 64 bit but I am unsure if the mysql gem is 64 bit as well(or does that matter?). I do know that my local mysql server is 64 bit although I am currently trying to migrate to remote mysql server.

Answer (score 1):

The [hive logic tutoria](http://hivelogic.com/articles/installing-mysql-on-mac-os-x)l worked for me for getting mysql installed.

However, unless you are doing full text searching or using gems that require mysql I would just stick with sqlite. It's an out of the box solution from Leopard 10.5 and up so It's just easier.

Comment: I am planning to do this remotely so my only option is mysql at the moment.