# Rails 3 Mysql rake db:create issue

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, macos, rubygems

I've recently upgraded to Rails 3 and am getting the following issue when trying to run `rake db:create` to create a mysql database of which has been defined in database.yml

Some info about my setup:

running snow leopard
rails gem v3.0.3
mysql gem v2.8.1
mysql 5.5.8

I'm presented with this issue:

$rake db:create

(in /Users/elliottheis/Sites/demoProject)

rake aborted!

**uninitialized constant Mysql::Error**

(See full trace by running task with --trace)

Does anyone have any ideas how to solve this, it's driving me nuts!

Comment: @Karpie d'oh, please see revised edit above

Comment: What's the output for `rake db:create --trace` ?

Comment: snippet of the output is: "uninitialized constant Mysql::Error /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:64:in `create_database' /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:33 /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `call' "

Comment: Did you ever get this to work? I'm having the same problem, and I can't understand what other steps I can take. I have done everything that you have, and I verified that I can connect to the MySQL database with the credentials I outline in my database.yml file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure Mysql is in your Gemfile and the database.yml is setup for Mysql. Uninitialized constant simply and will most likely always mean you have not told Rails where to find it. It you can type mysql -uroot into Terminal and see the Version then you know that MySql is fine. Try post a bit more information and we will see if we cant get to the bottom of this.

rake -r mysql db:create --trace

If this does not work then something has gone wrong in the installation. Try This.

Uninstall Mysql - Follow these [instructions](http://pastie.org/1466972)
Reinstall Mysql - Follow these [instructions](http://ozmm.org/posts/homebrew___mysql___snow_leopard.html)

Let us know how you get on and tell us the solution when you get it. All the best

Comment: It's already required in the gemfile "gem 'mysql', :require => 'mysql'" and mysql is working great it's just getting rails to interact with it... snippet from database.yml "development:
    adapter: mysql
    database: demoProject_dev
    host: localhost
    user: root
    password:"

Comment: type bundle exec rake -vT and see if rake db:create is there - if it is try bundle exec rake db:crate

Comment: It is in there yes. However when running "bundle exec rake db:create" am still getting the same error thrown back

Comment: Try rake -r mysql db:create --trace

Comment: The adapter should be mysql2 for Rails 3

Comment: if I change it to mysql2, I then get the error "uninitialized constant Mysql2"

Comment: @chuck "uninitialized constant Mysql::Error
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:64:in `create_database'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:33
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `call'
"

Comment: @chuck - still no luck following those instructions :(

Comment: Try specify you rake version in your Gemfile. Here is a post I wrote on the subject. - http://chuckjhardy.com/post/5704383770/rails-and-rake-0-9-0-dont-play-nice-together

Comment: @ChuckJHardy The rake command you gave above did not fail for me. It seems like rake can't understand the Gem I'm using, i.e. mysql?

Answer (score 1):

I know this has already been answered, but in case this happens to someone else, my issue was identical to Elliot's.

However, my fix revolved around using mysql gem 2.8 and Snow Leopard, which which is explained in [another Stackoverflow thread:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332207/uninitialized-constant-mysqlcompatmysqlres-using-mms2r-gem)

> As it turns out, that class should not exist; the error message is
>   caused by a problem with the latest Mysql driver. mysql-2.8.1 looked
>   for my libraries in a directory named with an extra level of ‘mysql’
>   at the end. For instance, my libraries (under MacOS X 10.5.8), are in
>   /usr/local/mysql/lib, but the mysql.bundle library looks for the MySQL
>   libraries at /usr/local/mysql/lib/mysql … which is wrong.

So I needed to install the mysql gem version before 2.8.  Follow the instructions on [this Web site](http://accidentaltechnologist.com/apple/fixing-uninitialized-constant-mysqlcompatmysqlres-error-on-snow-leopard/), and your issue should be resolved.