# Mysql gem causes MysqlCompat::MysqlRes error with Passenger only

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, passenger

I have a problem similar to the one outlined at [uninitialized constant MysqlCompat::MysqlRes (using mms2r gem)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332207/uninitialized-constant-mysqlcompatmysqlres-using-mms2r-gem)

Trying to run a Rails 2.3.14 application under passenger 3.0.9 with the mysql 2.8.1 gem on Snow Leopard I get an error:

uninitialized constant MysqlCompat::MysqlRes

However, this **ONLY** happens under passenger, I can interact with mysql through ActiveRecord through all other means: i.e. I can create models in script/console, rake db:migrate, tests and so on. The mysql gem has been built with with the correct ARCHFLAGS. Both ruby and mysql have been built 64 bit.

Other information: I'm using RVM, REE and bundler.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that this was caused by using the DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable to overcome the problem in the mysql 2.8.1 gem. This wasn't part of the apache environment, but was part of any user process spawned from the shell, hence it not working under apache.