# Error with the mysql gem

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm trying to start a rails application in my server. but i'm getting this error.

```
uninitialized constant MysqlCompat::MysqlRes
```

The rails version is 2.3.14 and ruby 1.8

Anybody know how to get this working?

Comment: This forum post might help - http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/192550

Comment: Couldn't find a solution from there.

Comment: What platform is this running on? Could it be you have a different location for the mysql libs? Also, what version of the mysql gem are you using? (run `gem list | grep mysql`).

Comment: Have a look also here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332207/uninitialized-constant-mysqlcompatmysqlres-using-mms2r-gem